# Can I use alma mater before graduating?

Tags: letter-writing, academia

I'm currently writing cover letters for my next position, and I want to refer to the institution I will graduate from. Can I use the term alma mater despite not graduating yet?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could simply qualify it for clarity’s sake: “soon-to-be alma mater”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. The term refers to [the school, college, or university where you studied](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/alma-mater) (Cambridge), so since you studied there the term technically should apply.

Comment: Although this might be so 'technically', such use of the phrase would be unusual, and possibly confusing.